# Expected a collection with size 2 but collection size was 0?

Tags: json, spring-boot, junit, mocking, hamcrest

I'm writing some code to test a web service using mockito and junit, so I faced a problem within the hasSize(2). I have injected the controller and calling the method findAll which returns a list of Employees, but error persists, in debugging mode it told me that the collection was empty, however, it is not.

the error is:

> java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$" Expected: a collection with
> size <2>    but: collection size was <0>

here is the class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class GestionPointage3ApplicationTests {

        private MockMvc mockMvc;
        @InjectMocks
        private EmployeController employeeController ; 
        @Mock
        private EmployeService employeeService;
        @Mock
        private ModelMapper modelMapper;
        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception{
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
            mockMvc=MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(employeeController).build();
        }

        @Test
        public void testgetAllEmployeeWithModelMapper() throws Exception{
            Employe emp1 = new Employe("Hamza", "Khadhri", "hamza1007", "123");
            Employe emp2 = new Employe("Oussema", "smi", "oussama", "1234");
            List<Employe> Employees= Arrays.asList(emp1, emp2);

            EmployeDTO dto1 = new EmployeDTO("Hamza", "Khadhri", "hamza1007", "123");
            EmployeDTO dto2 = new EmployeDTO("Oussema", "smi", "oussama", "1234");
            //when(modelMapper.map(emp1,EmployeDTO.class)).thenReturn(dto1);
           // when(modelMapper.map(emp2,EmployeDTO.class)).thenReturn(dto2);
            when(employeeService.findAll()).thenReturn(Employees);


            mockMvc.perform(get("/employe/dto"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].nom", is("Hamza")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].prenom", is("Khadhri")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].login", is("hamza1007")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].mp", is("123")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].nom", is("Oussema")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].prenom", is("smi")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].login", is("oussama")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].mp", is("1234")));

            verify(employeeService,times(1)).findAll();
            verifyNoMoreInteractions(employeeService);

        }

    }
```

and this is the Controller:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employe")
public class EmployeController {
    
    @Autowired
    private EmployeService employeService;
    
    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;
    
    @GetMapping("/dto")
    public List<Employe> findAll() throws Exception{
    return employeService.findAllEmployeActive(); 
    }   
}
```

method signature:

```
public List<Employe>findAll() throws Exception;     
public List<Employe>findAllEmployeActive() throws Exception;
```

StackTrace errors:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<500>     at
> org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:55)
> at
> org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:82)
> at
> org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:619)
> at
> org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:178)
> at
> com.cynapsys.pointage.GestionPointage3ApplicationTests.testgetAllEmployeeWithModelMapper(GestionPointage3ApplicationTests.java:66)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
> at..

Answer (score 1):

You are mocking `EmployeeService` and telling the mocked instance to return the `Employee` list (with its two items) when the `findAll()` method is invoked:

```
when(employeeService.findAll()).thenReturn(Employees)
```

But in the `EmployeeController` you are actually invoking a different method on `EmployeeService`:

```
return employeService.findAllEmployeActive()
```

So, you should update your mocked expectation like so:

```
when(employeeService.findAllEmployeActive()).thenReturn(Employees)
```

Comment: i changed it but it error change ti expected 200 but error 500

Comment: @HamzaKhadhri can you update your question to include the stacktrace for that 500 error and also include the method signatures for both `employeService.findAllEmployeActive()` and `employeService.findAll()`

Comment: You added the stacktrace from the test error i.e. the failed assertion. I'm looking for the stacktrace of the 500 Internal Server Error thrown by your mock server.

Comment: Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList[0]->com.cynapsys.pointage.model.Employe["actif"])

Comment: probably because you're mocking your model mapper